# Python openpyxl loop data in cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to loop the value 2 into the cells in the given range but when the script runs and I check my excel sheet the cells are empty.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.active

n = 1
ws.title = 'Day '+str(n)

ws['A1'] = 42


import datetime

ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

c = ws['A4']
ws['A4'] = 4

d = ws.cell(row=4, column=2, value=10)

cell_range = ws['A5':'A7']

for cell in cell_range:
    cell.value = 2

wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

what is the error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: The question originally listed the problematic assignment as `cell = 2`)

There are two problems.

First, in order to assign a value to a cell assign to the cell's `value` attribute:

```
cell.value = 2
```

Second, `for cell in cell_range` actually returns tuples containing columns of cells.  So the correct way to iterate is:

```
for each_column in cell_range:
    for cell in each_column :
        cell.value = 2
```

The reason `cell = 2` doesn't work is that assignment makes names refer to objects.  Before the assignment the name `cell` referred to one of the cells in `cell_range`.  Afterwords, the name `cell` referred to integer object `2`.  The cell object referred to by the name `cell` is unaffected by this assignment.

But if this is true why does `ws['A4'] = 4` work?  That's because `ws['A4'] = 4` is not assignment!  It's actually syntactic sugar for a method call `ws.__setitem__('A4', 4)`.  Because it's a method call it can actually mutate an object rather than just make a name refer to an object as in normal assignment.

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: @cojoe:  I would need to see your code.  It's saying that `cell` refers to a tuple but your code indicates otherwise.  Are you perhaps doing your iteration like this `for cell in enumerate(cell_range):`?